# django runserver error from SVN co

Tags: django, svn

I have written a Django project which runs fine on the dev server.  Although I am the only one working on it, I realized I should get some sort of version control going and placed the project on a network SVN.  I assume the new process for working this project should be: checkout code from SVN, make changes, test, update, and commit back to SVN.

However, when I check out the code and attempt to run the dev server from the checked out SVN location, I get an error that "has no module named yadda.yadda".  But, the module is there and it works fine when I run it from the original directory.  Any thoughts?  Any suggestions on a better work process?

Answer (score 1):

Does your $PYTHONPATH shell variable reference a relative path? If so, the relative path may be incorrect when you change to the new directory.

You can also diff the contents of the two directories to ensure that your versioned copy is a duplicate of the original.

Answer (score 0):

- Check if your module has **init**.py
- As George said check if module is on python path (import sys and print sys.path)

Comment: The module is one of the project's applications and has the init file.  It works fine when run from ~/pythonCode/Django/project.  When I checked out code from SVN to same directory ~/pythonCode/Django/SVNcode is when I have the problem.  This smells of a SVN issue with permissions now.